# HorizontalNumberPicker onclick

Tags: android

My question is : how can i handle the onclick method for ´+´and ´-´buttons? Could I do it in this class? [image]

```
public class HorizontalNumberPicker extends LinearLayout {
    EditText et_result;
    Button bt_plus;

    public HorizontalNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontalnumberpicker, this);
        et_result = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_hnp);
        bt_plus = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);

    }
}
```

The desired behaviour will be few interaction with the Activities or fragments, only a getter for the EditText.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_minus"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:onClick="plus_bt"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_hnp"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:onClick="plus_bt"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle touch events on your app just use:

```
bt_plus.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //do all your plus method like a increment integer and
                //et_result.setText("value");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Hope this help you.

Edited Start Activity when you touch the event just:
Inside your event handler:

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("Indetifier",the text integer);
startActivityForResult(i,0);
```

For fragments you can try:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                               .replace(R.id."containerindetifier", new SecondFragment())
                               .addToBackStack("1")
                               .commit();
```

Comment: I have tried, but I get : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Comment: On your class just try 
`int numeral = Integer.parseInt(et_result.getText().toString());`
Then 
`numeral++;
et_result.setText(Integer.toString(numeral));`
Make us know if it works ty.

Comment: I am getting the same issue